# Vim and gVim in Windows doesn't recognize Mongolian letters Өө and Үү

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, font, encoding

I'm trying to open and edit files with Mongolian text, written in Mongolian Cyrillic. In the cmd terminal and in powershell terminal if I choose Consolas font, everything is ok with Mongolian Cyrillic, letters Өө and Үү are displayed correctly. If I open any Mongolian files in terminal Vim or gVim window, it shows them as `?` sign. I have such an option:

```
:set guifont?
  guifont=Consolas:h9:cRUSSIAN
```

I added to _vimrc:

```
set encoding=utf8
set termencoding=utf8
set guifont=Consolas:h11:cRUSSIAN          "to get proper font for Cyrillic
set fileencodings=utf8,cp1251,cp866,koi8r
"to get English menu instead of broken Russian
set langmenu=en_US                        
let $LANG = 'en_US'
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
```

This code lets me see files properly. But I still can't type either search this letters straight in Vim. While typing, gVim turns them to `?`-s.

Please, give me some advise, what should I do to fix that problem?

Comment: Try to enable directx-based rendering (for gVim only), for example: `set renderoptions=type:directx,gamma:1.5,contrast:0.5,geom:1,renmode:5,taamode:1,level:0.5` (<- all in one line, no spaces) Also, use `:set guifont=*` and try different fonts by selecting them from a menu (gVim-only, too).

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really useful options, though I closed my problem another way.
Btw, you wrote about that yet: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2ex6kh/set_renderoptions_windows/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the decision was to update gVim to 8.0 version, released just a few weeks ago. Then such settings were useful as well:

```
set encoding=utf8
set termencoding=utf8
set guifont=Consolas:h11:cRUSSIAN          "to get proper font for Cyrillic
set fileencodings=utf8,cp1251,cp866,koi8r
"to get English menu instead of broken Russian
set langmenu=en_US                        
let $LANG = 'en_US'
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
```